# SWIG wrapper DLL for Ruby generated using VS2010 IDE is crashing

Tags: c++, ruby, visual-studio-2010, dll, swig

I have created a simple SWIG wrapper DLL for using it in Ruby. I've done this project using VS2010 IDE and the steps are mentioned in the link http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Ruby.html#Ruby_nn10

It's a simple wrapper DLL as given in the example above. 
But when I tried importing the DLL in Ruby require 'example' it's giving 'segmentation fault'.

I've done some investigation on this. I tried generating dynamic library using VS 2010 nmake. MakeFile for this was generated by using:
require 'mkmf'
create_makefile('example')

Generated example.so could be successfully imported in Ruby.

I noticed that there is considerable difference in size of dynamic library generated using VS 2010 IDE and nmake which is using the same compiler. First one was close to 824KB and second one was 11KB.

Can anyone suggest why the dll generated using VS 2010 IDE is crashing whereas generated using nmake is working fine with the same code including wrapper file?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the dll generated with VC 2010 was crashing because the RUBY_LIB used was static lib, whereas nmake was using the dynamic version of the RUBY_LIB library.